# How can I list every resource files of a directory pack URI?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, uri

I have many XML files with "Build Action" set as "Resource". I can access them from code using the well known pack URI scheme, or just a relative URI (which is actually a valid pack URI, as stated by Microsoft in the pack URI msdn page, so everything is a pack uri :p), like this :

```
Uri uri1 = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/someFolder/myResource1.xml");
Uri uri2 = new Uri("someFolder/myResource2.xml");
```

Actually, I need to get a stream from each xml file. What I can do is the following :

```
Uri uri1 = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/someFolder/myResource1.xml");
var stream1 = App.GetResourceStream(uri1).Stream; // works fine
```

It works fine and I get my streams. Now here are my questions :

**What if I do not know the names of my resources ?** (only the path to "someFolder")
**How can I list them ?**

I cannot use Directory.GetFiles since resources are embedded into the assembly. A possible solution is to set the build action of my resources as "Embedded Resources" and then use the `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` function, but I'm stubborn and do not want to change this build action :p

Thanks !

EDIT : I came to something like this :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a dictionary of the assembly resources (not embedded).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filter">A regex filter for the resource paths.</param>
    public static IDictionary<string, object> GetResources(string filter) {
        var asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
        Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resName);
        ResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(stream);

        IDictionary<string, object> ret = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry res in reader) {
            string path = (string)res.Key;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(path, filter))
                ret.Add(path, res.Value);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```